# HtmlAgilityPack skip or remove nested table

Tags: html-agility-pack

I’m using HtmlAgilityPack in order to retrieve the following html (notice the nested table):

```
<table class="123">
<tr>
    <table class="789">
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>def</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>info 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>info 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, I’m trying to find a clever way to obtain some information from the parent table and some information from the nested table…

So far I have the following:

```
var parentTable = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='123']").FirstOrDefault();

var nestedTable = parentTable.SelectNodes("//table[@class='789']").FirstOrDefault();
```

I can now play around with the nestedTable and get what I want (abc, def)...

But when I try to get the `<tr>`’s from the parent table like so:

```
var parentTableRows = parentTable.SelectNodes(".//tr");
```

It seems to include (in the collection) the `<tr>`’s from the nested table as well...

In other words, according to the above html code, I was expecting to have a collection of 4 `<tr>`’s but since it includes the `<tr>`’s from the nested table, I’m getting a collection of 6 `<tr>`’s.

How can I *skip* the first `<tr>` that happens to hold the nested table so I can play around and get the information I want (info1, info2, info3)
(hope I’m making sense…)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//` is an XPATH expression that means "scan all nodes and sub nodes". That's why `//tr` gets all tr below the root one.

If you just do `parentTable.SelectNodes("tr")` (or `"./tr"` which is equivalent), you will select all TR below the root one.

If you want to skip the first one, then you can add an XPATH filter on element's `position()` (an XPATH function):

```
var parentTableRows = parentTable.SelectNodes("tr[position() > 1]");
```